# USQL - Custom Outputter failed to find NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a USQL Job which reads json from Azure Blob and after some data manipulation writes a single line JSON file to ADLS.
I have written a Custom Ouputter to write JSON File.

This is how my CustomOutputter files look like:

```
    using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
    using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    namespace demo{

    [SqlUserDefinedOutputter(AtomicFileProcessing = true)]
    public class JSONOutputter : IOutputter
    {
     //Actual Code Here
     public static class Factory
    {
        public static JSONOutputter JSONOutputter(bool isHeader = true, Encoding encoding = null)
        {
        return new JSONOutputter(isHeader, encoding);
        }
    }
    }
```

I am using this Ouputter in my USQL Job like this:

```
    OUTPUT @final_output
    TO "/output/json/final.json"
    USING demo.Factory.JSONOutputter(isHeader: true);
```

When I compile my USQL Script using

```
ADL: Compile Script
```

I get this error:

```
    [Info] Start compiling code behind: /users/kumar.pratik/documents/usql/second.usql.cs ...
    [Error] Command failed: mono /Users/kumar.pratik/.vscode/extensions/usqlextpublisher.usql-vscode-ext-0.2.11/compilehost/compilehost.exe /users/kumar.pratik/documents/usql/second.usql.cs  /Users/kumar.pratik/Documents/usql/usqlCodeBehindReference /Users/kumar.pratik/Documents/usql/second.usql.dll __codeBehind__tRYGlFBeSWcl

    [Error] Compile failed

    error: "The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" at line: 8, column 6
    error: "The type or namespace name 'JsonTextWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" at line: 17, column 12
    error: "The type or namespace name 'JsonTextWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" at line: 44, column 34
```

Could someone please let me know how can I get this fixed?

I am working on Visual Studio Code on Mac OS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share how your script looks like? In particular, are you

1. Using Visual Studio's code behind for your Outputter code?
2. If the answer to 1 is no: Did you register your Outputter and Newtonsoft lib in the U-SQL catalog with `CREATE ASSEMBLY` or via the Visual Studio Assembly registration feature? And did you reference the U-SQL assemblies (both your own code and Newtonsoft) in your script with `REFERENCE ASSEMBLY`?

More details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/08/26/how-to-register-u-sql-assemblies-in-your-u-sql-catalog/

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding dlls however I am stuck with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583497/usql-jsontextwriter-writevalue-is-throwing-error-the-type-uri-is-defined-in-a Can you please help?